# I got given a strange plant a few days ago that I have never seen around this area, does anyone know what it is?

Tags: identification

[image] this is a pretty strange plant for northern canada. I need help identify this plant.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's some kind of [Castor Oil Plant](https://www.gardenia.net/plant/Ricinus-Communis-Carmencita-Castor-Oil-Plant).

Comment: It is! We used to grow them in our garden when I was young. They grow pretty tall (like 6ft).

Comment: Be aware that the seeds of Castor Bean Plant are very toxic to humans if ingested: http://poisonousplants.ansci.cornell.edu/toxicagents/ricin.html

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, will keep dogs away from plant and safe

Comment: @Ethan Pls. accept the answer if it answered your question.